# PHPMailer: Working on localhost, stuck after clicking "submit" button on the domain, gives Error 503, E-Mail arrives after 4mins

Tags: php, forms, phpmailer, http-status-code-503

So I've been trying now for two days to get rid of this problem.
As mentioned, the code works perfectly fine on my xampp apache localhost. The Email is send immediately.
However, on the domain which I have, once I press submit, it just loads and loads, and after 5mins or so gets a timeout, or rather a "503 Servive unavailable".
I've checked my local PHP error log, everything is fine.
I don't have access to the error log on the server though.

Here is the code for the form:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Ihr Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Vorname Nachname" class="form-control"  />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Ihre E-Mail Address</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="IhreEmail@server.com"  />
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Ihre Nummer</label>
        <input type="text" name="mobile" placeholder="Ihre Mobile 079 *** ** **" class="form-control" required/>
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label><i class="far fa-file"></i>Ihr Dokument für die Übersetzung</label>
        <input type="file" name="resume" accept=".doc,.docx,.pdf,.jpg,.bmp"/>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Ihre Nachricht</label>
    <textarea name="additional_information" placeholder="Welchen Service wünschen Sie? Wie sollen wir in Kontakt treten?" class="form-control" required rows="8"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="form-group" align="center">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Senden" class="btn btn-lg btn-success"/>
</div>
</form>
```

There is a include_once('mail.php'); in the index.php of course, where the form is at.
The mail.php looks like this:

```
<?php


use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

// HIDE ALL ERRORS
//error_reporting(0);
//ini_set('display_errors', 0);


$message = '';


if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {


    if ( isset( $_FILES['resume']['name'] ) && $_FILES['resume']['name'] != "" ) {

        $path = 'upload/' . $_FILES['resume']['name'];
        //print_r($path);
        print_r( $_FILES );

        move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["resume"]["tmp_name"], $path );
    } else
        $_FILES = NULL;
    $message = '
    <h3 align="center">Applicant Details</h3>
    <table border="1" width="100%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
        <tr>
            <td width="30%">Name</td>
            <td width="70%">' . $_POST["name"] . '</td>
        </tr>
    
        <tr>
            <td width="30%">Email Address</td>
            <td width="70%">' . $_POST["email"] . '</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="30%">Phone Number</td>
            <td width="70%">' . $_POST["mobile"] . '</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td width="30%">Additional Information</td>
            <td width="70%">' . $_POST["additional_information"] . '</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
';
    require 'vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
    require 'vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';
    require 'vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer( true );
    $mail->IsSMTP(); //Sets Mailer to send message using SMTP

    // ADD YOUR DETAILS HERE
    //$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; //Sets the SMTP hosts of your Email hosting
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.iway.ch '; //Sets the SMTP hosts of your Email hosting, this for Godaddy
    $mail->Port = '587'; //Sets the default SMTP server port
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; //Sets SMTP authentication. 
    $mail->Username = 'email@email.com'; //Sets SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'example'; //Sets SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; //Sets connection prefix. Options are "", "ssl" or "tls"

    $mail->setFrom( 'email@email.com', 'example' ); //Sets the From email address for the message
    $mail->addAddress( 'example@server.com' );
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
    $mail->WordWrap = 50;
    $mail->IsHTML( true ); //Sets message type to HTML
    if ( isset( $_FILES['resume']['name'] ) && $_FILES['resume']['name'] != "" ) {
        $mail->AddAttachment( $path ); //Adds an attachment from a path on the filesystem
    }
    $mail->Subject = 'Emaple Mail'; //Sets the Subject of the message
    $mail->Body = $message; //An HTML or plain text message body

    try {
        $mail->send();
        header( "Refresh:3; url=index.php" );
        exit();
    } catch (phpmailerException $e) {
        echo $e->errorMessage();
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

}

?>
```

The email name and PW are changed on purpose.
I am really at my wits end. That's my first Hompeage, everything else works just fine. Why does it send the Email after 5mins, but shows 503 and not the index.php again?
Thank you.

Comment: Make sure the set from addres is the same as your site and test without the attachement.

Comment: It’s most likely that your hosting provider is blocking outbound SMTP. The PHPMailer troubleshooting guide covers how to diagnose this in great detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should change [SMTP port](https://kb.iway.ch/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=27165741) and SMTP Secure to:

```
$mail->Port = '465';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: `Port` is an integer not a string, and port 587 is correct when working with SMTP+STARTTLS encryption mode in PHPMailer, so this answer is unlikely to help.

Comment: This worked, nice! So everything else was ok, only this was amiss! Thanks mate.